# Анимация синусоиды

Tags: java, android, android-animation

Есть прямая линия на всю ширину экрана. Нужно нарисовать анимацию синусоиды по этой линии, чтобы прорисовка синусоиды строилась бесконечно как на осциллографе.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, с чего начать вообще и/или у кого-нибудь есть похожие примеры кода? Буду признателен!

Comment: Посмотрите [этот ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33211722/3069565). Может оттуда что-то почерпнете.